# регулярные выражения. Как разделить строку?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть список названий городов через запятую, а также список синонимов названий в квадратных скобках.
пример - *Москва [Мск, Белокаменная], Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер], Ростов, Калининград*
Нужно поделить на списки из названий

1. *Москва [Мск, Белокаменная]*
2. *Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер]*
3. *Ростов*
4. *Калининград*

Разделить все названия просто

```
    String input = "Москва [Мск, Белокаменная], Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер], Ростов";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\[,\]]");
    String[] words = pattern.split(input);
```

А как вытянуть названия вместе с синонимами в квадратных скобках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам регулярные выражения, если задача решается простым линейным парсингом?

```
String input = "Москва [Мск, Белокаменная], Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер], Ростов";
List<String> words = new LinkedList<>();
int square = 0;
int start = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    switch (input.charAt(i)) {
        case '[': square++; break;
        case ']': square--; break;
        case ',':
            if (square == 0) {
                words.add(input.substring(start, i).trim());
                start = i + 1;
            }
            break;
    }
}
if (start < input.length())
    words.add(input.substring(start).trim());
```

Comment: В итоге так и сделал, только через split. Дело в том, что после нужно все названия и синонимы раскидать по связанным объектам

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант регулярки `,(?<=\],) ?` [тест на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/c07LPB/1)

```
String input = "Москва [Мск, Белокаменная], Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер], Ростов";
String[] words = input.split(",(?<=\\],) ?");
```

Результат 3 элемента [тест на onecompiler](https://onecompiler.com/java/3w962hwmr)

```
Москва [Мск, Белокаменная]
Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер]
Ростов
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `matcher`. Предполагается, что в названии города не может быть только открывающей квадратной скобки и запятой, зато пробелы могут быть. `(?!\s)` в начале срезает ненужные пробелы слева. Ссылка на регулярное выражение — https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd0tvj6r:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
String input = "Москва [Мск, Белокаменная], Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер], Ростов";
List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?!\s)[^\[,]+(\s*\[.+?\])?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
String[] words = pattern.split(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    cities.add(m.group());
}
```